# Magento 2 - Get Customer Address Id through Shipping Address at Checkout Session

Tags: magento2, street-address, magento2.2

I'm having trouble with getting customer address Id as it returns a null value.

This is what I have tried:

```
$checkout = $this->_sessionCheckout->getQuote();
if ($checkout) {
   $shippingAddress = $checkout->getShippingAddress();
   if ($shippingAddress) {
       $addressId = $shippingAddress->getCustomerAddressId();
       $this->_logger->log(100, print_r('address Id: ' . $addressId , true)); //Returns null 
       /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address */
       $address = $this->_addressRepository->getById($addressId);
       $address->setCity($city_name);
       $this->_addressRepository->save($address);
}
```

I just need to get customer address Id in order to update the city. I don't know why it returns a null value.

---

Edited Details:

The below image shows the saved shipping addresses:

[shipping-addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZF0X.jpg)

What I want to know is How to know the **customer address id** of each of those shipping addresses. So I can modify any details I want.

Answer (score 1):

When you place an order as a guest user, you have to add shipping address on checkout page at that time there will be not a customer reference object, so you get value of customer address Id to null.

When you place an order as a registered customer, you should have default shipping address, then only you can get the value of customer address Id.

This happen because `customer_address_id` is a reference to `customer_address` table and `customer_address` table reference to `customer_entity` table.

Comment: Hi thanks for the information. But my problem is that for a registered customer, I'm still getting customer address Id as null.

Comment: Do you know any other way to get customer_address_id of a registered customer?

Comment: You can get registered customer_address_id on checkout page, not on cart page. Have you checked that?

Comment: Yes. So When I do the following way:
$addressId = $this->_sessionCheckout->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCustomerAddressId();

The $addressId returns null value

Comment: Have you added default shipping address from My account section?

Comment: hi, I have edited my question above, please look at it. I'm showing you an image of the saved shipping addresses and the first address is the default shipping address

Comment: Ok. You can get mostly customer_address_id using same above code in checkout page if you have default shipping address for registered customer. Can you please check in quote_address table for customer_address_id column? Can you check any Id placed or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the order as follows
Wherever your want to invoke this information add following in the Constructor if not already being used.

```
protected $checkoutSession;
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }


    $order = $session->getLastRealOrder();
    $orderdata = $order->getData();
    $shipping_address_id = $orderdata['shipping_address_ID'];
```

> This address is the final shipping address selected during payment
> stage of the checkout process.